# PHP with DOMXPath - Select only a number of letters/numbers from a nodeValue

Tags: php, domxpath

Let's say we have a nodeValue '92/100' or 'some/all', or ' 92 / 100' and 'some /all  ' (with those spaces around the letters/numbers).

For example:

```
<?php

$strhtml='
<div>
    <div>
        <p>92/100</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>some/all</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p> 92 / 100</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>some /all </p>
    </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtml($strhtml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/div/p[1]');

foreach( $nodelist as $node ) {
    $result = $node->nodeValue;
}

echo $result;
```

How to select only '92' and/or 'some'?

Thanks.

Comment: `list( $pre,$post )=explode( '/', $node->nodeValue );`?

Comment: show some of your code where 'PHP with DOMXPath' were brought in

Comment: Hi @RamRaider, please check https://eval.in/506757 Could you modify it to retrieve, say item #4 so I can see how to apply your code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, here: https://eval.in/506757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this more or less what you were asking to do? Retrun the portion to the left of the `/` ?

```
$strhtml='
<div>
    <div>
        <p>92/100</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>some/all</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p> 92 / 100</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>some /all </p>
    </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($strhtml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/div/p[1]');

foreach( $nodelist as $node ) {
    list( $keep, $junk )=explode('/',$node->nodeValue );
    $result = trim( $keep );
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: you're welcome - consider accepting the answer if it helped so others know there was a solution - but up to you.